# Динамическая загрузка формы ввода данных с сервера

Tags: c#, база-данных, любой-язык

Интересует наличие такой технологии или способа разработки (ЯП на самом деле не имеет значения).

Пример:

Имеется приложение для CRUD-операций с записями в БД. При наличии связи с сервером записи напрямую изменяются в БД. При отсутствии связи с БД формируется xml-файл, который при подключении к серверу обрабатывается в соответствии со значениями в нём. Так же можно эти файлы автоматически отправлять через почту в аттаче, приёмник которых так же обрабатывает прикреплённый xml-файл.

Мысль:

Загружать так же с помощью xml-файла (или в любом другом формате) форму ввода данных, которая на основании внутренних параметров будет формировать не только поля ввода с определённым типом данных, но и логические условия взаимодействия между этими полями.

Вопрос:

Имеется ли технология, которая позволяет динамически - при загрузке приложения - вытягивать с сервера формы ввода данных?

P.S.: Вопрос именно в динамической подгрузке, т.к. у пользователя не всегда есть доступ к серверу БД, а формы будет обновлять по письму от разработчика.

Может сумбурно что-то написал, но **готов развить мысль**, если есть такая необходимость :)

Comment: Да, такие технологии существуют. Самая распространённая из них - веб. Любой сайт может динамически менять своё содержимое. При каждой новой загрузке (обновлении) странички может загружаться новый html (форма ввода данных) и javascript (логические условия взаимодействия). Дальнейшее развитие идеи - [Прогрессивное веб-приложение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Прогрессивное_веб-приложение) ([PWA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_application))

Comment: Но, вообще, это можно сделать на любом языке. Делайте именно так, как описали: загружайте файл с описанием формы и код в том или ином виде. | Если брать в расчёт именно C#, то посмотрите на технологию Click Once.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо Вам большое! Это именно то, о чём у меня бродили мысли в голове. Именно PWA :) Осталось только теперь разобраться, как Ваш ответ указать решением моего вопроса. Ещё раз - спасибо Вам большое!